# Parent web.config is not getting inheritted in child folders

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I came across strange behavior that, parent web.config file from web application project cant be accessed in sub folder.

i.e. unable to retrieve values from parent web.config in sub folder under IIS7.
Application pool is in classic mode.

**Also there is no web.config in sub folder.**

Comment: is sub folder set as application in IIS ?

Comment: No, its not an application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is virtual directory and physical path mismatch in applicationhost.config 
so corrected it manually and got resolved above error.